# Сложность в коде телеграм-бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Не могу понять проблему, читал документацию и попытался строчку подогнать под бота, вроде всё правильно, но все равно выходит ошибка.
использую telebot и PyTelegramBotAPI
P.S. каши из табуляций и пробелов нет

Вывод:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/bin/pythonanywhere_runner.py", line 26, in _pa_run
   code = compile(f.read(), filename.encode("utf8"), "exec")
 File "/home/bot/bot.py", line 38
   class telebot.types.ForceReply(selective: Optional[bool] = None, input_field_placeholder: Optional[str] = None);
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Код:

```
import telebot
import config

from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):

    # keyboard
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("test")
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton("test2")
 


    markup.add(item1, item2)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Добро пожаловать".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
        parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)

 class telebot.types.ForceReply(selective: Optional[bool] = None, input_field_placeholder: Optional[str] = None)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Что вы вообще хотите сделать?

Comment: force reply хотел сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самостоятельно нашел решение, оказывается нужно было обновить библиотеку pytelegrambotapi.

Answer (score -1):

```
pip install pytelegrambotapi
```

напиши вот это в консоль